# Not able to access event.currentTarget when locker service is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, locker-service

There's a question already asked regarding this here [Issue with event.currentTarget](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129925/issue-with-event-currenttarget)

According to Salesforce [Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183rMQAQ) , they've updated that it has already been fixed in almost all the servers (except eight as of now). But, for me it's still not working (it has already been shown as fixed in the instance I'm working on).

My code is as follows:-

**Component:-**

`<div class="slds-form-element__icon" onclick ="{!c.displayPopup}">`

**Controller:-**

```
displayPopup : function(component) {
        component.set("v.isDisplayPopup", true);
    }
```

**Renderer:-**

```
({
    rerender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superRerender();   
        helper.renderPopup(component, helper);
    }   
})
```

**Helper:-**

```
renderPopup : function(component, helper) {
        if(component.isValid() && component.get("v.isDisplayPopup")) {          
            var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
            var svgElement = selectedItem.querySelector("svg");
            var scrollableWrapElement = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollableWrap')[0];                                   
            var position = this.getPosition(svgElement);
            var wrapperPosition = this.getPosition(scrollableWrapElement);
            var notesPanelComponent = component.find('notesPanel').getElement();
            var noteObject = notesPanelComponent.querySelectorAll("div")[selectedItem.dataset.rownumber];            
            for(var i=0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".notes").length-1; i = i + 1){

                document.querySelectorAll(".notes:not(#\\3"+noteObject.id+")")[i].classList.remove('slds-visible');    

                document.querySelectorAll(".notes:not(#\\3"+noteObject.id+")")[i].classList.add('slds-hidden');         
            }
            noteObject.classList.toggle('slds-visible');
            noteObject.style.top = position.top - wrapperPosition.top + 35+"px";
            noteObject.style.left = position.left - wrapperPosition.left -127+"px";
            component.set("v.isDisplayNotes", false);
        }
}
```

When I click on that particular, it throws an error saying `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined]`

The `event` is undefined!

Can anyone tell me why am I not able to access the same here?

Is there any way so that I would be able to access the clicked DOM element from helper?

PS:- I'm trying to access the `event.currentTarget` from the helper via renderer (and not directly from controller) is because DOM manipulation is involved(which cannot be done outside the rendering lifecycle as per the Lightning Developer Guide), once I get the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

The code you list above would not work with LS deactivated - not an LS issue - renderer methods never receive events of any kind (component, helper) is the supported signature. This is not related to the other SE thread you referenced.

Why are you using a custom renderer at all for this instead of simply handling the event directly in the controller action method?

Comment: Hi @Doug It's because there's DOM manipulation involved. I've read in the Lightning Developer Guide that you're not supposed to make DOM manipulation outside the rendering lifecycle (except if aura default methods are used). Also, this worked before(and still works) when locker is deactivated, so I thought it was linked to the other one.

Comment: One more clarification. Sorry I didn't mention about DOM manipulation before. Also, it's not that event I meant. It's the browser event I meant. (I've edited the code.)

Comment: In your `displayPopup` method, just set the visible class of the popup (which is probably already in the DOM).

Comment: Hi @RowanChristmas Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I can do that (and I'm doing that too). But my requirement here is to display popup with dynamic contents at dynamic postions whose coordinates are manually calculated (using getPosition in JavaScript) and on click, the dynamic data is populated and then displayed.

Comment: An `event` is probably the way to go then... trigger the event wherever, and have the presenting component listen for it. I am doing this in order to manage multiple popups with different types of content.

Comment: @Doug Chasman I am able to access event.currentTarget from helper (Invoked from rerender) when locker service is deactivated and without passing event.

Comment: How - there is no symbol "event" in scope at that point? Where is event coming from?

Comment: @RowanChristmas Thanks for the suggestion. But the event which you said (and which invloves DOM manipulation) can be called directly from controller or helper right?  In the documentation, they're specifying not to manipulate DOM outside rendering lifecyle. Won't that be a problem during security review? (Although it might just work temporarily)

Comment: @DougChasman When locker is disabled, I'm getting the event (browser event without passing "event" as also confirmed ) and I am getting the required DOM element while calling currentTarget. But when locker is enabled, I am not able to do so. As I said before, I am trying to do this through rerender as it involves DOM manipulation as you'll be able to see the code inside helper. It would be very helpful if you could please advise on how to handle such a scenario. It is working fine when I call the helper directly from controller after passing "event". But it shouldn't be done, right?

Comment: @AravindAjith https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_intro.htm shows a number of examples, everything you seem to be doing looks to be derived from one of these examples.  My feeling is that you should be ok (I am taking this approach as well).  

What is the link for the specific wording on no DOM manipulation? It was probably in a release note that's in the dev guide that I missed....

Comment: @RowanChristmas `These libraries register event handlers and modify the DOM outside of the lightning renderer lifecycle. This can cause undefined behavior and breaks security policy.`  This was one of the statements which was given by the Salesforce team after security review. So, I'm very much concerned on manipulating DOM outside the rendering lifecycle myself (or using external libraries which manipulates the same or which are not compatible in JavaScript strict mode) which cannot be done using aura utils functions or so.

Comment: @AravindAjith That's a super unhelpful answer... and it feels like the presence of LockerService should make it so this sort of thing is not a problem. It's not like Angular/React **aren't** modifying the DOM outside the render lifecycle, and they're called out as one of the benefits of Locker Service :)  I'm going to talk to my local user group Monday to see if anyone has contacts I can use to get some clearer answers.